# Why is my decorated directive not overriding the original's methods in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Trying to follow the template in the Angular Decorator guide (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/decorators), I've tried to create a directive and decorate it.

The directive is supposed to show the current date/time. I added a (useless) decorator to modify the `link` function so the directive shows the string "today" instead of the date/time.

For some reason, it seems my overridden `link` function does not get called. The original gets called instead. Why is this?

Code is at http://plnkr.co/edit/uvtBiN5vNSjk5I89t99C?p=preview (and below):

```
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app').directive('myElement',  function(){
  return {
    template: 'Today is {{ date }}',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      console.log('original link called')
      scope.date = new Date();
    }
  }
})

angular.module('app').decorator('myElementDirective', function($delegate){

  $delegate[0].link = function(scope){
    console.log('calling delegate link')
    scope.date = "today"
  }
  return $delegate;
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When replacing the link function, the compile function needs to be replaced as well.

```
angular.module('app').decorator('myElementDirective', function($delegate){

  $delegate[0].link = function(scope){
    console.log('calling delegate link')
    scope.date = "today"
  }
  //------------------------------------
  //REPLACE compile function
  $delegate[0].compile = function() {
    return $delegate[0].link;
  };
  //------------------------------------
  return $delegate;
})
```

When the directive definition object (DDO) omits a compile function, the [$compileProvider.directive()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$compileProvider#directive) registration method adds one that returns a reference to the linking function. The compile function needs to be updated to return a reference to the new linking function.

The [$compile service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) ignores the `link` property of the DDO. It only uses the `compile` property.

Answer (score 3):

The link function is just syntactic sugar in AngularJS. If you use it, AngularJS will generate a compile function using that link function. But once that is done, replacing the link function will not have any effect.

Instead, you should replace the compile function with your own that returns the new link function:

```
angular.module('app').decorator('myElementDirective', function($delegate){
  var originalLink = $delegate[0].link;

  $delegate[0].compile = function() {
      return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        originalLink.apply($delegate[0], arguments);
        scope.date = "today";
      };
    };

  return $delegate;
})
```